# How to use custom HttpHandler with asp.net mvc in iis 7 and visual studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-7

I have created a `HttpHandler` that I would like to use with my asp.net mvc application (the version of mvc is not relevant). How do I make my `HttpHandler` to handle request to a certain directory? The actual file in the directory doesn't exist, but that is fine since I want to create the response. I want it to work in IIS 7 of course, but also in Visual studio for debugging purpose. When searching the internet for it I found that you register handlers in web.config under the `system.webServer` node like:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="MyHandler" path="/MyPath/*" verb="*" type="Namespace.To.MyHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

But my handler doesn't get fired.

Comment: Can @downvoter please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turned out that this is not what I want to do at all. What I ended up doing was creating my custom `IRouteHandler` and mapped a route to the folder I wanted my handler to use. My custom `IRouteHandler` only created a new instance of my already existing `IHttpHandler`, since I could use the same one. I will provide more info here later on.